# Footer doesn't adapt dynamically to page size

Tags: html, css

I have a footer div on my side, which should be at the very bottom, regardless of the content.

When the page loads, the footer looks good, but when another div loads much text, the text slides under the footers, so the footer doesn't dynamically adapt to the page size:

```
<style>
      #div1 {
      width: 300px;
      margin-top: 300px;
    }

    #footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
    }
</style>

<div id="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [ ... much text ...]</div>
<div id="footer">Footer Copyright 2016</div>
```

I know, `position: fixed` could solve my problem, but I want the footer to be "under" the content, not "over".

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4fjts5p4/

Comment: why not use a z-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you just use `absolute`, use also these, but I prefer `position: fixed`. This would be perfect:

```css
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

Use a `min-height` rather than `height`, which doesn't hardcode the height.

<s>Moreover, you haven't closed the `footer`'s `}` CSS rule.</s>

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned, I want the footer to be "under" the content, not "over". So if there is much text, the footer should always be at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: @user1170330 The feature you are asking is totally an entire different thing. It is called Sticky Footer.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly, what I was looking for.

Comment: @user1170330 Okay, will guide you for that. Check [**A CSS Sticky Footer that just works**](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 0):

Try position relative.

```
#footer {
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
}
```

If you use absolute it will take the footer outside the flow of the document.

[See this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/4fjts5p4/1/)

Comment: exactly what I also was about to post.. :)

Comment: This works, but only with much text. But if I have only few content, the footer is floating almost at the center of the page. But it should always stay at the very bottom.

Comment: @user1170330 why dont you give a min-height to the div?

Comment: @user1170330 Seems like I misunderstood what you was asking. Assumed you didn't want a sticky footer. Praveen Kumar's answer will do that.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set `position:relative;` and `height:auto;` . This will fix all your issues.

```
<style>
      #div1 {
      width: 300px;
      margin-top: 300px;
    }

    #footer {
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
</style>

<div id="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [ ... much text ...]</div>
<div id="footer">Footer Copyright 2016</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the footer and content both inside a div say its id is "wrapper" and its padding bottom should be same as footer height and its position should be relative. And then set the footer position to absolute with bottom 0.

So wrapper div code :

```
 #wrapper
    {
      position:relative;
      min-height:100%; /* in case if content is smaller than window size then footer will remain at bottom because of window this */
      padding-bottom:40px;/* same as height of footer */
    }
#footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background:#0c0;
      height: 40px;
      line-height:40px;
      }
```

**Working Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/4fjts5p4/4/**

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by structuring HTML like the bellowing, consisting `wrapper`, `content` and `footer`.

The key (also one drawback) is to **set the height of footer**,

A demo:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXjOam

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="content">          
    </div>

    <div id="footer">           
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom:100px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

/* For highlighting, you may not need this */
#footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    border-top:1px solid #ff4b02;
    color:#333;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```